# If value = NaN then

Tags: python, pandas, null, nan

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to use Pandas (I can use VBA but it takes quite a long time) to merge 2 sheets of Excel into 1 (Like Vlookup function in Excel). And I have a problem as below:

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'v_contract_number': ['VN120001438','VN120001439'],'maturity date': ['31/12/2021','31/12/2021']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'v_contract_number': ['VN120001438','VN120001439'], 'd_revised_maturity_date': ['31/12/2021',' ']})
print(df1)

# df1
  v_contract_number maturity date
0       VN120001438    31/12/2021
1       VN120001439    31/12/2021

print(df2)

# df2
  v_contract_number d_revised_maturity_date
0       VN120001438              31/12/2021
1       VN120001439  

results = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['v_contract_number'],how='left')
print(results)

# results
  v_contract_number maturity date d_revised_maturity_date
0       VN120001438    31/12/2021              31/12/2021
1       VN120001439    31/12/2021
```

What I want is if 'd_revised_maturity_date' is null then null = 'maturity date'

My expected result is:

```
  v_contract_number maturity date d_revised_maturity_date
0       VN120001438    31/12/2021              31/12/2021
1       VN120001439    31/12/2021              31/12/2021
```

I can do this task in excel with iferror but I don't know how to do in python.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you merged, you can use `mask`:

```
d_date = results.d_revised_maturity_date
results.d_revised_maturity_date = d_date.mask(d_date.eq(" "), results["maturity date"])
```

This will fill the empty slots of `d_revised_maturity_date` (found with `eq`ual to `" "`) with the corresponding values of `maturity date` column,

to get

```
>>> results

  v_contract_number maturity date d_revised_maturity_date
0       VN120001438    31/12/2021              31/12/2021
1       VN120001439    31/12/2021              31/12/2021
```

(If you're looking to replace any kind of whitespace in `d_revised_maturity_date` column, you can change `d_date.eq(" ")` above to

```
d_date.str.fullmatch(r"\s*")
```

which includes fully empty strings, one or more spaces.)

Answer (score 1):

```
df['d_revised_maturity_date'].fillna(df['maturity date'], inplace=True)
```

Should work for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, before answering older questions, please try to check if existing answers already cover what you would like to add. In this case, this is a duplicate of [Albin Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68312603/8944057). Also if appropriate, try to explain what your code is doing, e.g. short comment describing `fillna()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fillna` to fill na/nan values with another column.

```
df['d_revised_maturity_date'].fillna(df['maturity date'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of np.where() can be used to your advantage.

```
np.where(pd.isna(df["d_revised_maturity_date"]), df["maturity date"], df["d_revised_maturity_date"])
```

Answer (score 0):

results['d_revised_maturity_date'] = results['maturity date'].apply(lambda x: x if x == None else x)